# How can I use ROS Msgs ind Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I followed this tutorial http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.5/ros_enabled_model_plugin, but when I tried to add the header of an own messages, the compiler can't find the package. How can I fix this issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3579/how-can-i-use-ros-msgs-ind-gazebo/) by [Sebastian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/392/sebastian/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

First, you'll need to include a lot more info for us to help you - including your package.xml and CMakeLists.txt (assuming you are using catkin), your version of ROS, etc.

I suggest you look at this updated tutorial:
http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/Creating_ROS_plugins_for_Gazebo

Your tutorial link above is dead, by the way.

---

Originally posted by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) with karma: 369 on 2013-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0